# Jersey Client call not working outside of local environment

Tags: java, jersey, weblogic12c, jersey-client

I am attempting to make a call to a REST service using JerseyClient. It works in my local environment but once the code is moved to our development or QA environments it no longer works. It will also work if I paste the url in my browser, and it works in JavaScript if I call the url with an AJAX call, so I don't think the problem is with the service itself. For some reason the Jersey Client isn't working in the other two environments. The war with the REST services and the application ear are both deployed together in each environment. The code is straightforward and looks like any example code you'd find on the web.

```
Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
WebTarget target = client.target(url);
Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get();
String jsonString = response.readEntity(String.class);
```

Debugging isn't setup on either server so I don't know what exactly is happening. But if I hard code the development environment url locally, the Response status code is -1, and the message is Moved Temporarily.

Is there any reason why this would work locally and not elsewhere? Is there a configuration setting on the Client object I'm missing, or a setting on the server that I need to know about?

Comment: Please give more details like the exact URL you are trying to hit from your client. And the API method signature exposed. Use logger to log your executions. And check what is the error thrown and the stacktrace. Your Jersy client and your Jersey API both are deployed in same server ?

Comment: I'm not posting that. It's internal stuff and I'm not risking violating company policy. I know the URLs work as I can paste them into the browser and see the returned JSON.